# Key preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a table through a view but I keep getting the error that the columns don't map to a key preserved table. Can someone explain why this tables are not key preserved?

The error I get is:

> SQL Error: ORA-01779: não é possível modificar uma coluna que corresponde a uma tabela que não é mantida por chaves
>   01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
>              map to a non-key-preserved table.
>   *Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Code:

```
create table Pessoa
(
    cartaoCidadao integer check(cartaoCidadao <= 99999999) not null,
    nome VARCHAR(35) check(nome not like '%[0-9]%') not null,
    email varchar(35) not null,
    dataDeNascimento date not null,
    genero varchar(9) check(genero in('Masculino','Feminino')) not null,
    primary key(cartaoCidadao)
);

create table Membro
(
    cartaoCidadao integer  check(cartaoCidadao <= 99999999) not null ,
    nivel varchar(8) not null,
    primary key (cartaoCidadao),
    foreign key (cartaoCidadao) references Pessoa(cartaoCidadao),
    foreign key (nivel) references Escalao(nivel)
);

create table Escalao
(
    nivel varchar(8)  not null,
    primary key(nivel)
);

create or replace view membroView 
as
     select cartaoCidadao, nome, email, dataDeNascimento, genero, nivel
     from Pessoa 
     inner join Membro using(cartaoCidadao) 
     inner join telemoveis using (cartaoCidadao);

update membroView
set nome = 'Hello'
where cartaoCidadao = 123;
```

Comment: Please post the error details too. And also your Oracle version.

Comment: I added the error but I have no idea what oracle version i am on since this is a college assignement and we just work with what was given to us any way i can check it?

Comment: As far as I remember Oracle's `LIKE` does not match regular expressions like `%[0-9]%`. You'll need to use a function for regex.

Comment: Does that affect the table being key preserved? Because that check is working as intended.

Comment: Your view references an additional table, `telemoveis`, which you haven't provided the description of.

Comment: Ohhhhhh thank you i didnt even realize but i forgot to delete that inner joins and that in itself was making the error due to the way my table telemoveis is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Key preserved means the row from the base table will appear AT MOST
>   ONCE in the output view on that table.

(https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486)

It's not entirely clear yet since you haven't provided all the relevant table definitions, but essentially the error indicates that Oracle cannot guarantee that any given row in `Pessoa` corresponds to one or zero rows in the view.

Since `Pessoa` and `Membro` have the same primary key (which seems rather odd, by the way), this presumably means that the undescribed table `telemoveis` can have more than one row for a given value of `cartaoCidadao`.

Comment: i forgot to remove the reference to the table telemoveis that shouldnt be there but thanks for your answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

MEMBRO is the only key-preserved table in this query.  Any query from the view will return at most one copy of each row from MEMBRO, but it could return more than one copy of rows from PESSOA or ESCALAO if they are linked to more than one MEMBRO via its foreign keys.  Hence they are not key-preserved, and so you may not update PESSOA.nome.